# Под virtualenv не ставятся пакеты для Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

Захотел я тут написать веб приложение на flask. Проблема в том, что работать могу лишь под Windows, с Python проблем никогда не было.

Но тут мне понадобилось работать под виртуальной средой, а не под системным Питоном, но в ней не ставятся многие пакеты, например `flask` изначально выдавал ошибку, но помогла переустановка предкомпилированного `markupsafe`, теперь мне нужно установить flask-sqlalchemy и SQLAlchemy-migrate, ни то ни то не ставиться и выдает примерно одно и то же: (передаю картинкой ибо копировать из консоли не удобно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: Прежде всего обновите pip и попробуйте установить необходимый пакет ещё раз.

Comment: как и ожидалось, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Странно, не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему. Создал новое виртуальное окружение под Windows и легко установил в него flask, flask-sqlalchemy и sqlalchemy-migraion. Без прекомпилированных пакетов.

Comment: пользуетесь ли проксей под виндой?

Comment: Нет, причем тут это? Пакеты уже скачаны, но даже то что уже загруженности не устанавливается, тем болке, что например pip и numpy обновились без проблем

Comment: Первое - выполните команду(под виртуальной средой, естественно) pip install -r requirements.txt >output.txt Второе - пришлите сюда traceback из файла. Третье - вы же через requirements.txt указываете? Какие версии? Они на системном питоне нормально встают? Четвертое - я вижу по куску traceback-а, что идёт ругань на cygwin, кажется. Он установлен?

Comment: Про cygwin не знаю, под системным питоном все встаёт без проблем, устанавливаю без requirements.txt просто через pip install имя пакета, версии соответственно последние скачиваются

Comment: @NEStenerusnester возможно дело в том, что virtualenv более старой версии, т.е. после обновления pip попробуйте заново создать окружение и заинсталлить flask.